# Check on data modelling

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I would like to know whether my data modeling is working for Power BI.

The dataset I am using is training course for students and corporate. The original data has 3 tables separated by individual program. The purpose of my visualization is to analyze the 3 programs from all students in a single dashboard.

Here is the original data after being imported to Power BI:
[image: original data]

Here is the data pre-processing:

- Remove unneeded column

DPT table
Remove column – No, Date, Quarter
DTP table
Remove column – Count, Email, Date
LLD table
Remove column – Email, To calculate, Learning Hours

- Rename column name & impute missing value with “Not given”

DPT table
Trainee = Name, Training Provider = Provider, Course name = Course, Focus area = Domain
DTP table
Participant Name = Name, Event/Training Name = Course, Training providers = Provider

- Create new column and impute them with “No given” and put in same
  position (for append tables later)

DTP table
Level
LLD table
Company, Provider, Level

- Create a new column called Program and impute value as it program
  name for each row.

Post cleaned table:

[image: post cleaned table]

After appending the 3 tables and calling it Master:

[image: post append]

. Duplicate the Master table to create Student, Provider and Program table. In each table remove irrelevant columns, remove duplicates and create unique ID.

Final data model:

[image: final data model]

The focus is the Program, Provider and Student tables. The rest of the tables will be deactivated the relationship when creating calculated columns and measures before I make any correction to the data model.

Is there any proper approach to build the data model?

From my data model in the last picture, does it mean that the Provider table is a fact table while the Student and Program tables are dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with removing unneeded columns, renaming columns for a better look, and substituting 'Not Given' in place of NULLS (Caution here: Measures and Dimensions handle nulls differently, for dimensional values substituting is okay)

If modeling using PowerBI is a must, then the following strategy should happen:

1. The dimensions can be Students, Programs, Providers
2. A Factless Fact table (FactProgram or something like that). It will have dimensional keys to Students, Programs, Providers ( and additional measures that you can create or can be taken from Master )
3. Remove unnecessary columns from the dimensions, so that the Remove Duplicates will give you what you want. For instance, Student and Program currently have same columns coming from master (Company, Course, Domain, Level, Program, Provider). Make it clear which columns belong to which dimensions and optionally create new dimensions (maybe, DimCompany)

Comment: I need to form a relationship among the individual table to form star schema or snowflake schema. Even though importing the raw data into the Power BI also allow us to build any visualization but this is not the best practice.

Comment: I guess I agree if we are working with large file-based datasets. I have updated my answer

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I have some inquiries on 2 post due to word limitation. 

If I would like to separate the Company from Program table to form a new table, this will form a snowflake schema since I only able link both tables using relationship from company ID from the Company table. 

Secondly, I have Course ID in Program table and Student ID in Student table, I cannot merge the IDs in both tables to prevent circular relationship. Is this correct?

Comment: In star schema, the middle table is fact. In my final data model, the Provider table is fact but it does not contain any measure/data type in numerical form that allow me to do aggregation. Is this consider as fact?

Is it advisable to include Master table into the final data model? I may also can have Student, Provider, Program tables and have relationship with Master table by individual key on it to make it as a fact table. However, what is the Master table should I called it since Master is meaningless to the table it is just the result of the appending the 3 individual tables.

Comment: Snowflake schema - I do not know the context of the data. If the company is dependant on the program entirely then it makes sense to do so, I guess. if not, you can separate company to a different dimension, then put the CompanyDimKey (can be a surrogate) to the fact table
About the Fact without measures - yes, it is called a Factless Fact table and it has no measures, when only the events themselves are important (or nothing else is there) it can be used. 
About the Master table - No, you do not need it, other than maybe to verify that the data of the star schema and the Master is the same